# Braces missing return statements?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I'm currently writing a program where I have a string of methods all set up basically identical. If they're given i = 1, they'll return the price of the product times the quantity ordered. Otherwise, they simply returned the quantity ordered. Whenever I attempt to compile it, however, the compiler says that the brackets are missing return statements. I've gone through the code several times and I don't see anything overtly wrong in the syntax. Any guesses as to why this is happening?

Thank you for any help.

Relevant Source:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == switchCard)
            {
                cl.show(infoPanel, (String)candyList.getSelectedValue());
            }

        if (e.getSource() == checkoutButton)
        {
            double acidPops = acidPopsTotal(1);
            double bertieBotts = bertieBottsTotal(1);
            double bloodPops = bloodPopsTotal(1);
            double cauldronCakes = cauldronCakesTotal(1);
            double charmChoc = charmChocTotal(1);
            double chocoballs = chocoballsTotal(1);
            double chocCauldrons = chocCauldronsTotal(1);
            double chocFrogs = chocFrogsTotal(1);
            double chocWands = chocWandsTotal(1);
            double roachClusters = roachClustersTotal(1);
            double crystalPineapple = crystalPineappleTotal(1);
            double droobleGum = droobleGumTotal(1);
            double explodeBonbons = explodeBonbonsTotal(1);
            double fizzWhiz = fizzWhizTotal(1);
            double iceMice = iceMiceTotal(1);
            double jellySlugs = jellySlugsTotal(1);
            double liquorWands = liquorWandsTotal(1);
            double pepImpts = pepImpsTotal(1);
            double pinkIce = pinkIceTotal(1);
            double shockChoc = shockChocTotal(1);
            double spindleSpiders = spindleSpidersTotal(1);
            double quills = quillsTotal(1);
            double wizochoc = wizochocTotal(1);
        }
    }

    double acidPopsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (5.95* (Integer.parseInt(acidPopsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(acidPopsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double bertieBottsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (16.95 * (Integer.parseInt(bertieBottsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(bertieBottsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double bloodPopsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (5.95 * (Integer.parseInt(bloodPopsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(bloodPopsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double cauldronCakesTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (14.95 * (Integer.parseInt(cauldronCakesTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(cauldronCakesTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double charmChocTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (5.95 * (Integer.parseInt(charmChocTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(charmChocTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double chocoballsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (9.95 * (Integer.parseInt(chocoballsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(chocoballsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double chocCauldronsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (14.95 * (Integer.parseInt(chocCauldronsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(chocCauldronsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double chocFrogsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (14.95 * (Integer.parseInt(chocFrogsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(chocFrogsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double chocWandsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (9.95 * (Integer.parseInt(chocWandsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(chocWandsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double roachClustersTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (5.95 * (Integer.parseInt(roachClustersTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(roachClustersTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double crystalPineappleTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (9.95 * (Integer.parseInt(crystalPineappleTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(crystalPineappleTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double droobleGumTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (2.95 * (Integer.parseInt(droobleGumTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(droobleGumTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double explodeBonbonsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (9.95 * (Integer.parseInt(explodeBonbonsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(explodeBonbonsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double fizzWhizTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (9.95 * (Integer.parseInt(fizzWhizTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(fizzWhizTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double iceMiceTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (5.95 * (Integer.parseInt(iceMiceTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(iceMiceTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double jellySlugsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (2.95 * (Integer.parseInt(jellySlugsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(jellySlugsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double liquorWandsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (9.95 * (Integer.parseInt(liquorWandsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(liquorWandsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double pepImpsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (4.95 * (Integer.parseInt(pepImpsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(pepImpsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double pinkIceTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (4.95 * (Integer.parseInt(pinkCocoIceTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(pinkCocoIceTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double shockChocTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (4.95 * (Integer.parseInt(shockChocTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(shockChocTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double spindleSpidersTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (4.95 * (Integer.parseInt(spindleSpidersTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(spindleSpidersTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double quillsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (1.95 * (Integer.parseInt(sugarQuillsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(sugarQuillsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }

    double wizochocTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (5.95 * (Integer.parseInt(wizochocTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(wizochocTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:490: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:510: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:530: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:550: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:570: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:590: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:610: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:630: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:650: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:670: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:690: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:710: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:730: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:750: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:770: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:790: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:810: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:830: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:850: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:870: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:890: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:910: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java:930: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
Note: C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Java\4H 2012\ClientApp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
23 errors
```

Comment: Your `return` statements are nested in `try ... catch` blocks, what if they throw an error and don't return? There is no return value, this is why you are getting a warning. Put in a default return value at the end of the function.

Comment: Ah, there we go. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please work on your code style and indentation. It needs to be consistent and uniform. Code on the same level must be indented the same amount (I use 2-3 spaces). Else you will confuse us, and more importantly, will confuse yourself or your future self.

Comment: How is my indentation not uniform here? I believe that the code may be all one tab over because that's how it got copied into the question, but it's all fine in my actual source.

Comment: Hint: if you seeing a *lot* of repetition in your code, then your design is probably off. Try to create a single function that works for any product and any amount. If you are seeing a lot of constants in your code then you probably need to use a resource such as a file instead.

Comment: That.... is a remarkably good idea. Doing that now.

Comment: Look at your first two if blocks. They should be indented the same amount but are not. The second one is not indented enough and is actually indented to the same degree as its enclosing class. This is an important habit to get into.

Comment: It's a formatting issue in the question. The spacing is correct in my actual code.

Comment: Then please only post real well-formatted code. Avoid using tabs for indentations but instead use 2-4 spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no return guaranteed due to your try-catch blocks.

You might want to return a sentinel of 0 or -1 to show this.

An example that may make this more clear:

```
double acidPopsTotal(int i) {
    if (i == 1) {
        try {
            return (5.95* (Integer.parseInt(acidPopsTF.getText())));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Missing return - compile error
        }
    } else {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(acidPopsTF.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Missing return - compile error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java it is a compile-time error if there exists at least one path through a *non-void* function that does not contain a return or a throw. Because you catch a thrown exception and do nothing with it, nothing is returned in that path.  Hence, the error.

Aside: you might want to consider a program structure in which you *do* throw the exception instead of eating it.  (Then again, this is probably just example code.)

Comment: I'm not really worried about doing anything with the exception. This is for a fair project, and I'll be presenting it. I won't ever give input that would trigger the exception, so there's no reason for me to do anything with it.

If this was for actual production and distribution, then yes, I'd be sure to do something with the exception. If I have time, I may go back and do something with the exception, but not currently.

Comment: I understand.  My suggestion was to not have the try catch blocks at all and just allow the NumberFormatExceptions to be thrown.  Your code will be much, much, shorter and cleaner.  Since you aren't doing anything with the exceptions, that's IMHO your best strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what TheZ said is correct, there is potential for you to not return anything if an error is caught. Try something like...

```
 double chocFrogsTotal(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                return (14.95 * (Integer.parseInt(chocFrogsTF.getText())));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {return -1.;}
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(chocFrogsTF.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {return -1.;}
        }
    }
```

then whenever you return a value less than 1, you know you had a bad parse.